# How to build embedded ActiveMQ Broker?

Tags: c#, .net, activemq-classic, porting, nms

i'm doing a porting of a Java application in C# and i need to build embedded ActiveMQ instance.

In Java i can use **BrokerService** class but i can't find something similar in *Apache.Nms* namespace for .Net.

It could be useful to know how to start ActiveMQ jar with specific port parameter.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4):

Apache NMS ActiveMQ is a client only, not a message broker so there is no equivalent to BrokerService etc.  You can always run an external broker and connect to it via the NMS client.  There have been reports of people running ActiveMQ brokers using IKVM to host a Java VM in the .NET application but that seems like a hack and I don't recommend it as you still end up need to connect via TCP etc so you don't benefit from VM based transports or or shared memory operations that embedded ActiveMQ Java applications might do.

Comment: Thanks to reply.
I tried to start ActiveMQ in a new process and it seems to work,but how can i change the default port via command line if it use a config file?

Comment: That's unrelated to the original question and either needs a new question or a read of the documentation.